# How can I put an Html <form> tag inside a PHP function, which would redirect me to another .php file?

Tags: php, html

I have been searching for hours on the web and I just can't seem to find an answer.

What I want to do is put a `<form>` tag inside a php function which would redirect me to another x.php file if a certain criteria is met.

Comment: And what have you tried? Please post your code here...

Comment: what you need is `header('Location: x.php');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds simple enough:

```
function myFunction() {
    if ( Some Condition Here ) {
        ?>
             <form action="x.php">
                 <button>submit</button>
             </form>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Obviously the "redirect" won't happen until the form is submitted. Redirecting is done in response to an HTTP request not to "having a form".

Answer (score 0):

You don't use form to redirect , you use a header

```
function redirect(url){
  header("Location: ".url);
  die();
}
```

so now

```
if(some_condition){
  redirect("anotherFile.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirect use following code:

```
header('Location: page.php');
exit;
```